# Values ​not refreshing properly on page change with bootstrap + react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, bootstrap-5

I am making a component in React to paginate questions. The questions come from different components (representing tests with questions). Some of these questions are answered with checkbox or radiobutton. I give an example so that the error can be seen: I have a collection of questions in an array (within a "Test" component), and we pass it to the "Pagination" component. Here we see the example array with multiple choice questions with 2 example checkboxes, and how we pass it to the "Pagianacion" Component:

```
    const dataTest = [
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 1</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 2</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 3</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 4</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 5</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 6</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 7</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 8</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>,
        <><div className="row"><div className="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"><span>Question 9</span></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-1" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Yes</label></div></div><div className="col-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"><div className="form-check"><input id="formCheck-2" className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /><label className="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">No</label></div></div></div></>
    ]

    return (
        <>
        <Paginacion elementsList={dataTest} currentPagePar={0} rangePagesPar={5} /> <-- We write 5 elements per page. And we pass the array of elements "dataTest". The default page is "0" in this example.
        data 
        </>

    )
```

Next here I show the "Pagination" component. We see that in the piece of code " fullList.slice" it selects the segment of the array that I want to display with a simple calculation:

```
export const Paginacion = ({elementsList, currentPagePar, rangePagesPar}) => {

    const [fullList, setFullList] = useState(elementsList)
    const [currentList, setCurrentList] = useState([])
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(currentPagePar)
    const [rangePages, setRangePages] = useState(rangePagesPar) //10 items per page.

    const changePage = (page) => {
        setCurrentPage (page);
    }

    useEffect(() =>{

        console.log ( currentPage * rangePages);
        console.log ((currentPage * rangePages) + rangePages);
        /*
        let dat = [];
        for (let i = index; i < (index + rangePages) && i < fullList.length; i++){
            dat.push(fullList[i]);
        }
        console.log (dat);
        setCurrentList(dat);
        */
    }, [,currentPage]);


    return (
        <>
        {
            //Calculate init index (it depends ont the current page) to show the questions, and the number of elements to show (its rangePages) <---- LINE SHOWS HTML ELEMENTS
            fullList.slice(currentPage * rangePages, (currentPage * rangePages) + rangePages).map((current) => (
                <>
                {current}
                </>
            ))
        }
        <nav>
            <ul className="pagination">
                {
                    (() => {
                        //Draw pages numbers.
                        let valD = fullList.length;
                        let totalPages = valD / rangePages;
                        if (valD%rangePages !=0) totalPages += 1;
                        const retArray = [];
                        retArray.push(<li key={"\"init\""} className="page-item"><a className="page-link" aria-label="Previous" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li>);
                        if (valD%rangePages !=0) totalPages += 1;
                        for (let index = 0; index < totalPages; index ++){                            
                            retArray.push(
                                <li key={index} className="page-item"><a className="page-link" href="#" onClick={() => changePage(index)}>{index}</a></li>                                
                            );
                        }
                        retArray.push(<li key={"\"end\""} className="page-item"><a className="page-link" aria-label="Next" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>);
                        return retArray;
                        
                    }                    
                    )()
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </>
    )

}
```

**The problem**: when I change the page to show other questions, the text of the question is changed correctly, but the results that the user has entered in the checkbox (example) or in the radiobuttons DO NOT change to the new value, the ones that were there are kept on the previous page.
In the images I show the error:

1. The questions on page 1 are displayed.
2. I make changes to the checkboxes of the questions on page 1.
3. Page change and the texts of the questions on that page are displayed correctly, but the results displayed are those of the questions on page 1. The questions on page 2 are not displayed! I attach the screenshots. What am I doing wrong?
   [image: First step: page 0, just loaded test]
   [image: Second step: page 0, I put some answers in some questions]
   [image: Third step: I change the page to 1, and It draws the results of the previous data]

---------------- EDIT ------------
I change this part:

```
            //Calculate init index (it depends ont the current page) to show the questions, and the number of elements to show (its rangePages)
            fullList.slice(currentPage * rangePages, (currentPage * rangePages) + rangePages).map((current, i) => (
                <>
                <li key={(currentPage * rangePages) + i}>
                {current}
                </li>
                </>
            ))
```

The problem may be here, in the unique keys as the first answer comment says. Now it seems that the IDs are simply not generated correctly, because when changing the page the values are simply deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noticing a few issues, whenever mapping or looping through something and rendering JSX, you need to add a unique string key like so:

```
{
  fullList.slice(currentPage * rangePages, (currentPage * rangePages) + 
  rangePages).map((current, i) => (
                <React.Fragment key={current.id}> // Required by React's diffing algo, should not use index if order will change.
                {current}
                </React.Fragment>
  ))
}
```

Relevant docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

It's also not a good idea to set state from props, instead you can pass the state and method to set the state as props down to your component. For example:

```
// No need to set props as state, pass these down from parent component.
const [fullList, setFullList] = useState(elementsList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
The <key={`fullList-${i}`}> tag gives me a syntax error.
I have visited the link that you attached me for the react keys, and I can't find examples similar to that. The idea would be to extract the index that this element occupies in the array, that could be a good unique ID. Is this possible to do?

Comment: No problem! You can use the index that comes from the second arg of the map callback


`const result = array.map((item, index) => console.log(index))`


You could try using React.Fragment instead of <> OR use a div instead:

```<div key={`fullList-${i}`}> {current}</div>```

Comment: Also can you share the syntax error if the above does not fix the issue?

Comment: Thank you. with:                 <>
                <div key={fullList-${i}}>
                {current}
                </div>
                </>
The syntax error is: Identifier expected.ts(1003). Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?ts(1382)
On the other hand, I think that if I use the index as id, I'm going to have repeated ids (if I can't use the fullList - ${i} which I think you suggest because it intends to generate a unique id per item, although I don't know very well how it does it.I have also tried the indexOf(current) of the array to generate an id, without success.

Comment: One additional thing to note is that the index is only recommended as a last-resort fallback. Ideally, each question would have a unique identifier. A revision to how the questions are passed in, changing from an array of Elements to an object (`[{ label: "My First Question", id: "q1" }, /* etc. */ ];`) and creating a separate`<Question />` element, would enable this, reduce duplication, and better align with standard React patterns.

Comment: Aaaah, I get the point. mm well, maybe I will create the key in the top level, I think its gonna be the cleanest solution. Thank you, I think this thread its the solution for this issue!

Comment: Hello again. I've created a simple Help Element that simply stores a key and the HTML of each question. Now there is another problem: when I change the page, the changes in the checkbox/radiobutton are not saved. Is it necessary to use a useState to save them each time they are clicked? It should save itself.

Comment: It could be the component unmounting, you may need to move  your state up so that the parent container holds the state and the child just displays it.